# A holomorphic funtion on an open connected domain, with $f(z_0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic funtion on an open connected domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}.$ Suppose $f$ is not the zero function. If $z_0$ is a zero of $f$, there exists a neighborhood $U \subseteq \Omega$ of $z_0$ such that $f(z)\neq0$ for all $z \in U \setminus \{z_0 \} $.

In these posts they do it using the series expansion:

- [All the zeroes of analytic $f$ in $A$ are isolated, or $f \equiv 0$ on $A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233748/all-the-zeroes-of-analytic-f-in-a-are-isolated-or-f-equiv-0-on-a)
- [Complex analytic functions and their zeros.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183025/complex-analytic-functions-and-their-zeros)

But I was told to use the principle of analytic continuation; and I have not clue how to use it here.

Comment: How do you define analytic continuation?

Comment: Let $\Omega \subseteq \Omega'$ two open connected domais on $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $f$ and $F$ holomorphic over $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ respectively. If $f(z)=F(z)$ for all $z \in \Omega$, we say that $F$ is the analytic continuation of $f$ to $\Omega'$.

Comment: Do you know anything about uniqueness of continuations?

Comment: Yes, we prove it in class.

Comment: Typically one uses this fact about isolated zeros to prove the uniqueness of analytic continuations. Did you approach uniqueness of analytic continuation without this fact?

Comment: For the uniqueness, we use the fact that if a holomorphic function $f$  on an open connected domain vanishes in some sequence with limit point on $\Omega$, then $f$ is the zero function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126128/discussion-between-ciaran-o-raghaillaigh-and-george).